# Update visibility of record on the basis of the value of multiple other records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am using the following query in a stored procedure to update cvUpd.visible to 0 or 1 when cvFrom.value is 1, 2 or 3. As can be seen I use the OptionRestriction table to determine what optionvalues in configvalue should be visible or not, depending on whether the value of other optionvalues in configvalue is 1 or 0 (I only included 1's and 0's for the value in the table to keep the example simple).

```
UPDATE cvUpd
SET cvUpd.visible = case cvFrom.value when 1 then 0 when 2 then 0 when 3 then 0 else 1 end 
FROM ConfigValue cvUpd
INNER JOIN OptionRestriction r ON cvUpd.ConfigurationID=67571
   AND cvUpd.FeatureID = r.Feature_ID_2
   AND cvUpd.OptionValue= r.OptionValue_2
INNER JOIN ConfigValue cvFrom ON cvFrom.FeatureID =r.Feature_ID_1  
   AND cvFrom.ConfigurationID = cvUpd.ConfigurationID 
   AND cvFrom.OptionValue=r.OptionValue_1
   AND cvFrom.FeatureID = r.Feature_ID_1
   AND cvFrom.value=r.value
```

This is my OptionRestriction table:

```
+---------------+---------------+-------+--------------+---------------+---------+
| Feature_ID_1  | OptionValue_1 | value | Feature_ID_2 | OptionValue_2 | visible |
+---------------+---------------+-------+--------------+---------------+---------+
|           399 |             6 |     1 |          403 |             2 |       0 |
|           399 |             6 |     0 |          403 |             2 |       1 |
|           399 |            14 |     1 |          403 |             2 |       0 |
|           399 |            14 |     0 |          403 |             2 |       1 |
|           776 |             1 |     1 |          403 |             2 |       0 |
|           776 |             1 |     0 |          403 |             2 |       1 |
+---------------+---------------+-------+--------------+---------------+---------+
```

The code to create the table above is:

```
CREATE TABLE OptionRestriction(
   Feature_ID_1  INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,OptionValue_1 INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,value         INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Feature_ID_2  INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,OptionValue_2 INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,visible       BIT  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO OptionRestriction(Feature_ID_1,OptionValue_1,value,Feature_ID_2,OptionValue_2,visible) VALUES (399,6,1,403,2,0);
INSERT INTO OptionRestriction(Feature_ID_1,OptionValue_1,value,Feature_ID_2,OptionValue_2,visible) VALUES (399,6,0,403,2,1);
INSERT INTO OptionRestriction(Feature_ID_1,OptionValue_1,value,Feature_ID_2,OptionValue_2,visible) VALUES (399,14,1,403,2,0);
INSERT INTO OptionRestriction(Feature_ID_1,OptionValue_1,value,Feature_ID_2,OptionValue_2,visible) VALUES (399,14,0,403,2,1);
INSERT INTO OptionRestriction(Feature_ID_1,OptionValue_1,value,Feature_ID_2,OptionValue_2,visible) VALUES (776,1,1,403,2,0);
```

This is my ConfigValue table:

```
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+---------+
| ConfigurationID | FeatureID | OptionValue | Value | Visible |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+---------+
|           67571 |       399 |           6 |     1 |       1 |
|           67571 |       399 |          14 |     0 |       1 |
|           67571 |       776 |           1 |     0 |       1 |
|           67571 |       403 |           2 |     0 |       0 |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+---------+
```

The code to create the table above is:

```
CREATE TABLE ConfigValue(
   ConfigurationID INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,FeatureID       INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,OptionValue     INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Value           INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Visible         BIT  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO ConfigValue(ConfigurationID,FeatureID,OptionValue,Value,Visible) VALUES (67571,399,6,1,1);
INSERT INTO ConfigValue(ConfigurationID,FeatureID,OptionValue,Value,Visible) VALUES (67571,399,14,0,1);
INSERT INTO ConfigValue(ConfigurationID,FeatureID,OptionValue,Value,Visible) VALUES (67571,776,1,0,1);
INSERT INTO ConfigValue(ConfigurationID,FeatureID,OptionValue,Value,Visible) VALUES (67571,403,2,0,0);
```

The problem with my query is that now only optionvalue 6 from feature 399 is able to update visible from optionvalue 2 from feature 403 to 0 or 1, depending whether its value is 0 or 1.

What I actually want to achieve is to update visible from optionvalue 2 from feature 403 to 1 when the values from optionvalue 6 and 14 from feature 399 and optionvalue 1 from feature 776 is 0, like this:

```
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+---------+
| ConfigurationID | FeatureID | OptionValue | Value | Visible |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+---------+
|           67571 |       399 |           6 |     0 |       1 |
|           67571 |       399 |          14 |     0 |       1 |
|           67571 |       776 |           1 |     0 |       1 |
|           67571 |       403 |           2 |     0 |       1 |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+---------+
```

When one or more values of optionvalues 6, 14, 1 from feature 399 and 776 are updated to 1, visible from optionvalue 2 from feature 403 should be updated to 0, like:

```
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+---------+
| ConfigurationID | FeatureID | OptionValue | Value | Visible |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+---------+
|           67571 |       399 |           6 |     1 |       1 |
|           67571 |       399 |          14 |     0 |       1 |
|           67571 |       776 |           1 |     0 |       1 |
|           67571 |       403 |           2 |     0 |       0 |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+---------+

+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+---------+
| ConfigurationID | FeatureID | OptionValue | Value | Visible |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+---------+
|           67571 |       399 |           6 |     0 |       1 |
|           67571 |       399 |          14 |     1 |       1 |
|           67571 |       776 |           1 |     0 |       1 |
|           67571 |       403 |           2 |     0 |       0 |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+---------+

+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+---------+
| ConfigurationID | FeatureID | OptionValue | Value | Visible |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+---------+
|           67571 |       399 |           6 |     0 |       1 |
|           67571 |       399 |          14 |     0 |       1 |
|           67571 |       776 |           1 |     1 |       1 |
|           67571 |       403 |           2 |     0 |       0 |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+---------+

+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+---------+
| ConfigurationID | FeatureID | OptionValue | Value | Visible |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+---------+
|           67571 |       399 |           6 |     1 |       1 |
|           67571 |       399 |          14 |     1 |       1 |
|           67571 |       776 |           1 |     0 |       1 |
|           67571 |       403 |           2 |     0 |       0 |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+---------+

+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+---------+
| ConfigurationID | FeatureID | OptionValue | Value | Visible |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+---------+
|           67571 |       399 |           6 |     0 |       1 |
|           67571 |       399 |          14 |     1 |       1 |
|           67571 |       776 |           1 |     1 |       1 |
|           67571 |       403 |           2 |     0 |       0 |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+---------+

+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+---------+
| ConfigurationID | FeatureID | OptionValue | Value | Visible |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+---------+
|           67571 |       399 |           6 |     1 |       1 |
|           67571 |       399 |          14 |     1 |       1 |
|           67571 |       776 |           1 |     1 |       1 |
|           67571 |       403 |           2 |     0 |       0 |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-------+---------+
```

How can I achieve the above using my update query and the OptionRestriction and ConfigValue tables?

Comment: What are the potential values in the 'Value' column of 'ConfigValue' table?

Comment: In the value column, the values 0,1,2,3 can be stored up to now (corresponding to the case in my update query). Or do you mean something different?